I have a "depth" problem with z-index during transiton
I want the clicked box to be most top during transition. I tried some ways but couldn't figure out. This is short (minimized) form of code. I removed my failed tries like loops etc. to achive my aim. This is an image gallery project and have more divs. Thank you in advance.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FVe3ZQwHj0KGbf5Q_PZUmChh8ULWDL0M/view?usp=sharing

My guess is you are transitioning z-index by transition: all 1s too. And please add your code here as a snippet.

As I said in the comment, z-index was in transition too. You have to write all properties in the CSS out.


    const container = document.querySelector('.container');
        const pics      = document.querySelectorAll(".pic");
        const gap       = 5;
        const rows      = 2;
        const columns   = 2;
        const minSize   = 100;
        const maxSize   = 500;
        const length    = pics.length;
        var index       = 0;
        var i           = j = 0;

        container.style.width  = 2 + gap + columns * (minSize + gap) + "px";
        container.style.height = 2 + gap + rows    * (minSize + gap) + "px";
        const rectBig          = container.getBoundingClientRect();

        init = () => {
            for(let index = 0; index < length; index++){
                i = index % columns;
                pics[index].style.left       = gap + i * (minSize + gap) + "px";
                pics[index].style.top        = gap + j * (minSize + gap) + "px";
                pics[index].style.width      = minSize + "px"
                pics[index].style.height     = minSize + "px"   
                pics[index].style.background = pics[index].dataset.color; 
                if(i == (columns - 1)) {
                    j++;
                }
                click(index);
            }
        }

        click = (index) => {
            pics[index].onclick = () =>{    
                if(pics[index].dataset.pos == 1){
                    reset();
                }
                else {
                    reset();                        
                    up(index);
                }
            }
        }

        reset = () => {
            i = j = 0;
            for(let index = 0; index < length; index++){
                i = index % columns;
                pics[index].dataset.pos  = 0;
                pics[index].style.zIndex = 1;               
                pics[index].style.left   = gap + i * (minSize + gap) + "px";
                pics[index].style.top    = gap + j * (minSize + gap) + "px";
                pics[index].style.width  = minSize + "px"
                pics[index].style.height = minSize + "px"       
                if(i == (columns - 1)) {
                    j++;
                }       
            }
        }           

        up = (index) => {
            pics[index].style.zIndex = 99;
            pics[index].dataset.pos  = 1;
            pics[index].style.width  = maxSize + "px";
            pics[index].style.height = maxSize + "px";
            pics[index].style.left   = rectBig.right - rectBig.left + gap + "px";
            pics[index].style.top    = 0 + "px";
            /* pics[index].style.transition = "1s all ease-out" */;
        }

        init();
.container {
            position   : relative;
            left       : 20px;
            top        : 20px;
            background : #Ece;
            border     : 1px solid #0008;
        }

        .pic {
            position    : absolute;
            border      : 1px solid #0008;      
            transition  : width 1s ease-out, height 1s ease-out, left 1s ease-out, top 1s ease-out;
            cursor      : pointer;
            user-select : none;
        }
<div id="container" class="container">
        <div class="pic" data-pos="0" data-color = "#800"></div>
        <div class="pic" data-pos="0" data-color = "#080"></div>
        <div class="pic" data-pos="0" data-color = "#008"></div>
        <div class="pic" data-pos="0" data-color = "#840"></div>

    </div>




Thank you so much. I will mention you in my code when I share my project. ;)
